# Screen not drawing properly despite the view child being greater then 0

Tags: java, android

I am programmatically setting creating views based on results I am getting back from the backend. But the screen remains blank. I don't understand what I am doing wrong given that my Log is telling me that the resultPlane view does have children.

This is what the screen looks like:

[image]

This is where I am getting LinearLayout from the screen to populate with TextView children

```
LinearLayout resultsPlane = findViewById(R.id.resultsPlane);
        resultsPlane.invalidate();
        resultsPlane = displayResults(resultsObject, resultsPlane);
        resultsPlane.requestLayout();
        Log.i("Child Count","" + resultsPlane.getChildCount());
```

Here is the code from the "displayResults" method

```
private LinearLayout displayResults(JSONObject resultsObject, LinearLayout resultsLinear) {
        try {
            JSONArray resultsArray = resultsObject.getJSONArray("Results");
            for(int count = 0; count < resultsArray.length(); count++){
                //Constraint Layout to contain all results
                //ConstraintLayout resultView = new ConstraintLayout(getApplicationContext());
                JSONObject result = resultsArray.getJSONObject(count);
                //Set ID
                //resultView.setId(count);

                //Set Service Name
                String serviceName = result.getString("Name");
                TextView service = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                service.setId(count);
                service.setText(serviceName);
                service.setWidth(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                service.setHeight(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                service.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                //resultView.addView(service);

                //Add Layout to Linear Layout
                resultsLinear.addView(service);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultsLinear;
    }
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the lack of `LayoutParam` on the `TextView`s. Try calling `service.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))` instead of setting via `setWidth` and `setHeight`